# What is the shortest and easiest way to pass custom data to survey js result?

Tags: surveyjs

I would like to pass form id to my backend but i couldn't find an easier way.

I tried to modify result and include my custom data like this

```
result.data.formid = myformdata.formid;
```

but it doesn't add it to the result, i would appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the way result.setValue("newproperty", propertyval);